# Environment.CurrentDirectory getting set to system32; how do I determine where?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

My problem is that, somewhere, somehow, and only sporadically, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` gets set to `C:\Windows\System32` when my test suite is running. A few tests depend on the current directory, and they fail as a result.

I've done a find-all in my project and confirmed that none of my code is setting that property. I use numerous 3rd-party libraries though, so my suspicion is that one of them is modifying the current directory.

I've done some searching specifically for the current directory changing to system32, but I've come up empty. Are there some common reasons why this might happen?

The other approach, which similarly came up empty, is: how might I track down the culprit? As far as I know, I can't have Visual Studio break anywhere when a value has changed. Because it's an environment variable and in the .NET libraries, I can't set a breakpoint in the setter.

I thought of using procmon or something, which hopefully records when the current directory has changed, but then it's not pausing the execution when it happens, so I still have no idea where it occurred.

I'm just at a loss as to how I might debug this. Any ideas? Or is my only recourse to save `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to a global readonly field and refer exclusively to that in my code, allowing whatever it is to modify the current directory with impunity?

Comment: Why do your tests need to know what the current directory is? Wouldn't it be better to determine the running assembly's path?

Comment: @stuartd Trust me, if I had written them, they wouldn't rely on the current directory... It is a good point however that this may all be moot in that nothing truly ought to be using the ebvieonment variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a very bad approach to do unit testing that relies on external sources. When somebody else will test your code, the unit tests depending on the current directory might fail.

Why don't you use Microsoft Fakes to return a specific value for the Directory?

In order to create a fake, in the reference of the Unit Test, right click the reference and click on "Add Fakes Assembly".

For Example, if your unit test relies on the Current Date, a Fake can generate another date/time with the following code:

```
ShimDateTime.NowGet = ()=> new DateTime(2012, 12, 21);
```

I recommended reading this post. It's of a very high value: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=963

Comment: This would be very inconvenient as he would have to recreate that Shim for each unit test just to fix a weird behavior by a third-party library. I would rather go and either 1) make the test *not* rely on the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` path or 2) try to find the library that is causing that and fix it or 3) use the executing assembly path like already suggested by @stuartd. You also need to note that Microsoft Fakes is only available with Visual Studio Ultimate.

Comment: There is business logic which also uses the current directory, so it's not strictly to do with unit tests. That said, you are probably still right, in that everything which uses it probably ought to use the executing assembly's path instead. Surely there are valid reasons to use the current directory though, which means there is value in answering the question as asked, so I hope if you don't mind if I don't accept this answer for now.